# Show that if $\omega$ is a 1-form differential, then $\left\vert\int_{C}\omega\right\vert\leq ML$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Show that if $\omega$ is a 1-form differential define on $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $c:[a,b]\to U$ is a differentiable curve and $\vert\omega(c(t))\vert\leq M$, for all $t\in [a,b]$, then $$\left\vert\int_{C}\omega\right\vert\leq ML$$
where L is a lenght of c.

I think with Poincare's lemma is useful for this, but I don't know why.. regards!

Comment: You need to use the definition: what does it mean to integrate a $1$-form $\omega$ along a curve $c$? Have you ever shown how to obtain the "canonical bound" for a complex line integral, i.e. for $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ and $\sigma$ a curve in $\Omega$, $$\left| \oint_\sigma fdz\right| \leqslant  \Lambda(\sigma)\max_\sigma |f|$$

where $\Lambda$ stands for length? This is very similar.